# Shell script/sed expression to add/echo extension with space in name

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I am trying to take this example file as input:

./chExt1.sh 'a b' 'mouse.ext'

and get 'mouse.a b' as output, using this current script. The error I'm encountering is:

```
~/UnixCourse/scriptAsst> ./chExt1.sh 'a b' 'mouse.dat'
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command
a b

mouse.dat
mv: cannot stat `mouse.dat': No such file or directory
```

my current script is:

```
#!/bin/csh                                                                      
set ext="$1"
set oldName="$2"
set newName=`echo "$oldName" | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$/'.$ext'/g'`
#set newName=`echo "$oldName" | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$/'.$ext'/g'`   
echo "$ext"
echo "$newName"
echo "$oldName"
mv "$oldName" "$newName"
```

What am I missing that will get the file to echo an extension with spaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

do you need to use regex? If you only use:

```
echo ${2%.*}.$1
```

you get the same result:

```
$sh script 'a b' 'test.dat'
test.a b
```

Comment: I do, I can only make modifications to my current sed script as I'd had to slowly modify it as I encountered various problems.

Answer (score 0):

`.$ext` contains space, so it should be enclosed in `"..."`

```
set newName=`echo "$oldName" | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$/'".$ext"'/g'`
```